# How to "open with" in python using webbrowser

Tags: python, open-with

I wanted to know if there was a way to open files using web browser module in python, but other than the default program.

So when we right-click a file, there is an option called `open with >` right? So, how can I use **web browser** to open with other programs.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new(path of file)
```

When I use the above, it opens the file with the default program. So for example, if I use this to open a .txt file, it will open it in notepad as it is the default. How do I make it so that it opens with other applications like - Word or something.

Thanks for any help or suggestion!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

Look this page - https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

controller.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
Display url using the browser handled by this controller. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible.